# Regex match until specific word or character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to retrieve some CPU models from a list but the list has some HTML tags how can I exclude the  tags but only keep the brand + Model such as "**Intel Core i7-4700HQ**" or "**AMD A8-6410**"

```
<span>Intel Core i7-4700HQ</span>
<span>AMD A8-6410</span>
<span>AMD A10-5745M APU</span> 
<span>Intel I5-4210U</span>
```

I've got

> (((Intel)|(AMD)).+)

However that picks up the  tags as well.

Comment: If you just want the text without the tags there are better(more efficient) ways than a regex. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any language as I do not have much knowledge or know which one would be best for this purpose. But, i'm using an extension called "Web Scraper" for  Chrome, attempting to retrieve some laptop product information off a specific website.

Comment: You could cleanup the string first, removing any tags, i.e. replacing all instances of "\<.*?\>" with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern. It basically means, search for "Intel" or "AMD" keywords. Include either keyword followed by any characters up until an angle bracket character.

`((Intel)|(AMD))[^<>]*`